# Where should one direct questions regarding integration of software?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently a friend of mine wanted to get some help regarding a solution for conference booking software to be integrated with SharePoint. He has tried several integration programs but in vain. I suggested him to ask this question on Stack Overflow so that he could get the necessary advice for the same. His question was closed on the grounds of not being programming related. The questions is available in *[Conference Room Booking Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963423/conference-room-booking-solution-closed)*.

I know that Stack Overflow deals with only programming-related questions, but what about integration software like [TIBCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibco_Software#Products), [Informatica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatica#Main_products) or SharePoint? Where should these questions be directed at? Server Fault? I think it would be great if the moderators suggested where the question should be posted, if it can be relevant to Server Fault, Meta Stack Overflow or Super User.

I've also found that most of those new to posting questions on Stack Overflow are treated very harshly by down voting/closing questions in spite of the questions being very genuine. I really love Stack Overflow, but these are some of the concerns I've wanted to post for a very long time.

Comment: Not an answer to the general question here, but have you checked out [SharePoint Overflow](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)? I would recommend searching there to see if anyone else has inquired about Conference booking, and if you find naught then check to see if SharePoint solution integration questions in general are allowed.

Comment: I didn't know that sharepointoverflow existed. The question was bluntly closed. It would have been great if the moderators directed us yesterday itself.

Comment: Are you under the assumption that every 3k+ person who can cast a close vote should know all the other web sites?  You didn't know about the other site, why do assume that everyone else should have known?  The people that choose to close only have to know if the question is appropriate for the site they are on.  It is up to you as the asker to find the right place on the Internet to ask.

Comment: It appears that your friend's question was quite reasonably received on [SharePoint Overflow](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/conference-room-booking-solution)

Answer (score 1):

The question you reference was correctly closed as having no programming content.  I know nothing about Sharepoint, but another package you mention, Tibco, certainly is programmable (it's on my CV) and questions regarding programming with it would definitely be on-topic on SO.

As with any site, newbies should either read the FAQ or lurk before posting. Otherwise they risk being "harshly" treated, though I don't think simply having  a question (which probably took less than a minute to type) closed can be considered "harsh".

Comment: My point is about giving a direction to newbies. It is well within the SO guidelines to close the question, but the moderators CAN direct where the questions can be posted. 

Also, someone has downvoted my question for a reason not mentioned. I think when someone downvotes anything, they should provide a valid reason why they are doing it.

Comment: @Snehal, There are 2,500+ people that are able to cast a close vote on SO.  Do you believe that every single one of them should know the correct place for every offtopic question?  If someone knew the right place they probably would have provided the link, like you got here on meta.  It is still your responsibility as the asker to do some research before asking to make sure you are asking the right people.

Comment: @Zoredache: Point well taken. But couldn't this be a feature for all Stackexchange applications? Maybe just provide an optional dropdown box to suggest where the Question might be posted. Not everyone might be knowing it, but someone out of of 5 people who have voted to close it might know. This is especially important, considering there are 100+ stackoverflow clones out there in the internet.  

I'm not here to vent my frustration because someone closed the question. I'm just suggesting that this could be one good way to do it. I wanted a normal discussion about. Sorry if I sound very "Harsh"

Comment: @Snehal: Then users would get upset when the person closing does not suggest the right site. It's best to not say anything at all actually and just close the question as not programming related.